# Software to censor out something in a video

Tags: linux, video, video-editing

I'm searching for an application that is able to censor out some text (a password) within a video that I made. It is only a very simple task.

Comment: Could you add more details like what format the video is in?

Comment: Plus what you mean by "censor out": do you want to cut out some frames, or use a kind of blur effect on a selected screen area? Also, must the software be free – or would you be willing to pay (in the latter case, how much)? While on it, please have a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) (I know there's not much more to add if this task is really the only thing you want to do, but it might be helpful for the future. But you could consider additional options for a video editor ;)

Comment: I think ffmpeg might be able to do this.

Comment: It is in the .ogv format. I just wan't to make a black bar over a screen are, nothing fancy.